# Nvidia RTX 2060 not recognised, HDMI not working

Tags: dual-boot, 19.04, hdmi

I'm at my wits end here. I'm running 19.04 in dualboot(same SSD) with win 10.

On win10 everything is peachy; HDMI and mini display both work perfectly.

Come to Ubuntu 19.04, everything fails. Neither port works(xrandr never pulls up hdmi port as below):

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+  60.01    60.00    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27
```

And I've tried everything Google has. All failed. I installed and switched to LightDM, no use. I reinstalled, have gdm3 only running, no use. Any ideas? This is getting super frustrating :(

Connecting the laptop to my dell monitor brings up the message from the monitor: `No hdmi signal from your device`

ADD: I've switched back from proprietary nvidia-driver-418 to noveau drivers, with no luck either. I opened nvidia settings and am currently running on the iGPU selection.

I ran optirun xrandr and came up with this:

```
[  120.658383] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[  120.658412] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled
```

I've switched to running the Nvidia high perf gpu setting(my RTX 2060) in nvidia-settings, restarted but to no avail. Its funny how an OS supported by Amazon has pretty much zero driver/hardware/paid-dev support rofl.

UPDATE:

I just realised my RTX 2060 isnt even recognised in the software&updates-Additional Drivers GUI...

```
Nvidia Corporation: Unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a [bug posted](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe/+bug/1826711) on installing via .DEB which repository installation solved, so I'd remove the old proprietary drivers first, run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and install the most current drivers available.

Answer (score 1):

Gonna close this question but I have honestly no clue how. Even Nvidia-435 popped up mysteriously. For the record, my secure-boot is already disabled, and I run the storage in AHCI mode(wouldnt be able to install in dualboot otherwise anyway)

What i did was:

1) Do a complete fresh install of ubuntu 19.04

2) Purge all nvidia drivers with `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`

3) Go to Software & Updates ; switch additional drivers to nvidia 435(that automagically appeared in this fresh installation) and my RTX 2060 is still NOT recognised there, shows `NVIDIA Corporation: Unknown`

4) Open up nvidia settings from terminal

5) Switch to using the intel iGPU (word on the net is using the dedicated Nvidia GPU will block usage of the HDMI/DP port) 
6) Reboot

And viola! It works. Sort of. Its all a hit and miss rn. Sometimes the cable works immediately. Most times I gotta pull it out and reinsert the thing like a monkey ten times before the monitor registers. If i used the miniDP port previously then the HDMI port doesnt register for 9/10 tries. And vice versa. WHY. The ports honestly feel like a timebomb rn. I got no clue when if ever, this fix will fail and I'll have to switch laptops again.

But, temps and battery life have definitely greatly improved. I get close to the same 6 hours on my laptop here as with Windows 10. User experience is pretty awesome now save for when I need to dual monitor for work.

But GOD, UBUNTU, FIX YOUR SHIT.